# Multi dimensional array and pointer in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
    int a[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << *a << endl;
    cout << &a[0][0] << endl;
```

The output of this code is:

```
     0x7fff3da96f40

     0x7fff3da96f40

     0x7fff3da96f40
```

However, if `a` is `0x7fff3da96f40` then `*a` should be the value in the address `0x7fff3da96f40` which is `1`.

But, we get the same address again.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try `*a = 0` and you see in the error message what `*a` is. This is not int.

Comment: `a` is `int (&)[2][2]`, `*a` is `int(&)[2]`, `a[0][0]` is an `int&`. The first two decay to pointer.

Comment: It happens because `a` *isn't* `0x7fff3da96f40` – `a`is not a pointer but an array. The value you see is its decay into a pointer to its first element, `&a[0]` (and that first element is also an array that decays into a pointer to *its*  first element when you print it).

Comment: @Jarod42 Excuse my nitpicking, but they aren't references. Expressions can't have reference types.

Comment: Very often, when you think "if A is true, then B should happen, so why doesn't B happen?", it is because A isn't true.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I hesitate to remove the one for `a` to match `decltype` behavior [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/75oTnEGc9).

Comment: @Jarod42 Decltype adds fake reference-ness to signal the value category.

Answer (score 3):

> `*a` should be the value in the address `0x7fff3da96f40`

It is. The key is *what type* the value has, and that type is `int[2]`.

`cout` can't print arrays directly, but it can print pointers, so your array was implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element, and printed as such.

Most uses of arrays do this conversion, including applying `*` and `[]` to an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you try

```
int a[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
cout << a << endl;
cout << *a << endl;
cout << &a[0][0] << endl;
cout << typeid(a).name() << endl;
cout << typeid(*a).name() << endl;
cout << typeid(&a[0][0]).name() << endl;
```

the possible output is

```
0x7ffe4169bb50
0x7ffe4169bb50
0x7ffe4169bb50
A2_A2_i
A2_i
Pi
```

So now you can see what types are the variables you are using. They are somewhat different entities, starting on same memory address.